# Gtk2hs give runtime error "Require gtk+ version 3"

Tags: haskell, runtime-error, gtk2hs

I am writing a small application using the gtk2hs, but i get the below error on running the application.

> required gtk+ version 3.10, current version is 2.24

Also i checked (using ldd) that the below library is linked to my application.

> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00000036aee00000)

I do have gtk version 3 installed on my machine. But still the application is using the version 2 of library.

> /lib64/libgtk-3.so
>   /lib64/libgtk-3.so.0

How can I resolve this issue?
Do I need to specify some GHC argument to link the gtk3 lib?

Comment: Have you installed the `gtk3` package in Haskell (rather than `gtk`)?: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is mentioned by vivian.
Here I am adding a couple of more things which were required to get the application working.

First install gtk3

> cabal install gtk3

Then specify that you want to use the gtk3 package. (As the below functionality is present in both "gtk" and "gtk3" packages)

> import "gtk3" Graphics.UI.Gtk

and finally compile with

> ghc -XPackageImports file.hs